# Break loop with button click Appdesigner GUI [Working in Debug Mode But Not in Normal Mode] [Both plot and button are in different functions]

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-app-designer

I have solved with my attempt but this is running only on "Debug mode" and not in "Normal Mode"

I have a Appdesigner GUI MATLAB. I have a button, and there is a loop like this

```
function RUN()
t=1:0.01:3600;
for i=1:numel(t)
    y(1,i)=readValue();
    plot(t(1:i),Tco(1:i));
    pause(0.02)
end
end
function BUTTON_PRESS()
   %BREAK FROM THAT LOOP
end
```

I want to break this loop when I click my button

### My attempt(WORKS IN DEBUG MODE BUT NOT IN NORMAL)

2nd pic: In appdesigner inside a callback to a button "PLOT AND SIM" I passed a function main_plot_function()

1st pic: shows that main_plot_function Now "STOP BUTTON " appears but clicking on that it doesn't stops loop of plotting nor it print "BUTTON!!"

[image]

[image]

But none of them worked.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: thank you @halfer I will take care next time!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increasing the pause timer worked seamlessly to break the loop!